# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version : 9.3.2.0 - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: azure

I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (Azure Storage SDK for Windows) version : 9.3.2.0 for uploading the blob.

Here is logic of c# code for the same.

```
private class FileBlock
     {
         internal string Id { get; set; }
         internal byte[] Content { get; set; }
     }
     public static async Task<Uri> UploadFileToAzureStorageAsync(string azureStorageUri, string filePath)
     {
         var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
         var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(azureStorageUri));
         var blocks = new HashSet<string>();            `enter code here`
          
         try
         {
             foreach (var block in GetFileBlocks(bytes))
             {
                 cloudBlockBlob.PutBlock(block.Id, new MemoryStream(block.Content, true), null);
                 blocks.Add(block.Id);
             }
             await cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blocks);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Logging.logger.Error(ex);                
         }
         return cloudBlockBlob.Uri;
     }
     private static IEnumerable<FileBlock> GetFileBlocks(byte[] fileContent)
     {
         if (fileContent.Length == 0)
             return new HashSet<FileBlock>();
         var maxBlockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
         var hashSet = new HashSet<FileBlock>();
         var blockId = 0;
         var index = 0;
         var currentBlockSize = maxBlockSize;
         while (currentBlockSize == maxBlockSize)
         {
             if ((index + currentBlockSize) > fileContent.Length)
                 currentBlockSize = fileContent.Length - index;
             var chunk = new byte[currentBlockSize];
             Array.Copy(fileContent, index, chunk, 0, currentBlockSize);
             hashSet.Add(new FileBlock
             {
                 Content = chunk,
                 Id = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(blockId))
             });
             index += currentBlockSize;
             blockId++;
         }
         return hashSet;
     }
```

I am seeing this issue intermittently for few packages. If i publish again it will be successful. I read few blogs which suggest to change machine to UTC time zone. I tried that as well but still the same error occurs as shown below.
I wanted to know if there is issue for the below exception.

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

StatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
ErrorMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Thanks,
Sangamesh

Comment: How does your Azure Storage URI look like?

Comment: You're using a SAS token with access policy. Can you share the details of that access policy like what permissions are included there and what's the expiry date of that access policy?

Comment: Sure @GauravMantri. Give me sometime i will share the details to you.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri is this how i can get access to policy and expiration date which mentioned in this blog post. I am relatively new to Azure. https://avanishtech.medium.com/restrict-shared-access-signatures-with-azure-stored-access-policy-c90fd455f67c

Comment: Can you share the value for the expiry date and permissions in your access policy?

Comment: @GauravMantri I don't have access to get those details from my account. I am checking at organization level to get those details.

Comment: We are planning to migrate from this version of storage SDK to latest one. Do you have any blog post or guide lines for achieving the same.